# how to apply scan filter below api 21 in android for ble device scanning

Tags: android

```
ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder().
setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString("02366E80-CF3A-11E1-9AB4-0002A5D5C51B")).
build();
```

I can succesfully apply scanfilter above 21 api, but it is not applicable below 21. How to apply this?

Answer (score 0):

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(LeCallback);
```

use this for scan for below lolipop and filter it `onLeScan` method based on scan record.